# codeigniter public directory in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, directory, url-rewriting

In example:

```
- index.php
- /system
- /application
   - /controller
      - test.php (class:test ; function index() ; echo "hi")
- /public
   - style.css
```

I point the browser to http://mysite.com/ it will show "hi"

If I want style.css, I must point to http://mysite.com/public/style.css

But I want to point http://mysite.com/style.css can show style.css too

I tried move index.php into public add prefix ../ before system and application

Also I setup a htaccess in root directory,then I can successfully point http://mysite.com/style.css for style.css

But there's another problem,I can't point to my test controller anymore,it show error 404

How can I keep both url?

**UPDATE:**

htaccess in root dir:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^public/.+$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ /public/$0 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

when I visit http://mysite.com/style.css can show style.css

but the controller test in not work,I visit http://mysite.com/test/test/index show 404 not "hi"

Comment: It makes sense to have it in /public/ and call it via /public/style.css; what's the problem with that? Also, please post your .htaccess.

Comment: it seems to be a problem with your rewrite rules within htaccess, post your htaccess for more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) if the requested file is from the public directory

```
# prevent requests for the public directory from being rewritten
RewriteRule ^public/.+$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ /public/$0 [L]
```

You must insert this rule before the Codeigniter rule, because otherwise the file could be rewritten to `/index.php/...`.

**Update**:

First, you must leave out the `RewriteCond !-f/!-d`.

The URL for `test/index` must be `http://mysite.com/test/index` or `http://mysite.com/test`.

Comment: this can show the css file,but my controller is 404 nt found,I updated the question

Comment: @jkjk Show the complete .htaccess in your question.